# DataTable AsEnumerable().ToList i can not make it work

Tags: c#, linq

I can not make this work. What should i do to make it work ? Thank you

```
    public static List<int> lstAllMonsterIds = new List<int>();

        using (DataTable dtTemp = DbConnection.db_Select_DataTable("select MyId,Name from myTable"))
        {
 lstAllMonsterIds = dtTemp.AsEnumerable().ToList(dtr => Convert.ToInt32(dtr.Field<Int16>("PokemonId").ToString()));                           
        }
```

Comment: -1, you show no research effort at all. What have you tried to resolve it? Do you get error messages? Do you get some output that was incorrect? *Why does it not work according to your needs?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `List<int>` back, then select the field using `int`, and don't call `ToString` on it, and in the end call `ToList`

```
lstAllMonsterIds = dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(dtr => dtr.Field<int>("MyId"))
                         .ToList();
```

If your field is of type `Int16`, then it can be implicitly casted to `int` or `Int32`, you don't have to call `ToString` on it and then Convert it to `Int32`